# SQL Case When Taking Too Long To Execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the most recent lt.creationdate inside my case statement. Right now, it is working correctly, but it is taking almost 2 minutes to execute.
However, If I put the

```
and lt.CREATIONDATE = (SELECT MAX(lt.creationdate)
    FROM dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
    WHERE lt.PARENTACCOUNT = l.PARENTACCOUNT
        AND lt.type = 54)
```

code in the where clause, it gives me incorrect data.

Here's my query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @UserName AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @StartDate = '2019-11-01'
SET @EndDate = '2019-11-30'
SET @UserName = 'YEN NGUYEN'

SELECT q.[User ID]
    , q.[User Name]
    , COUNT(q.Loans) OVER (PARTITION BY q.[User ID], q.[Loan Description]) AS [Loans]
    , q.[Loans] AS [Account Number]
    , q.[Loan Description]
    , q.LoanBalance AS [Loan Balance]
    , q.[Loan ID] AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(q.[Debt Protection]) AS [Debt Protection]
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
    l.USERCHAR2 AS [User ID]
    , ucat.UserName AS [User Name]
    , l.PARENTACCOUNT AS [Loans]
    , l.balance AS [LoanBalance]
    , l.ID AS [Loan ID]
    , CASE WHEN (l.type >= 1 AND l.type <= 299)
        THEN 'Auto Loans'
        WHEN (l.type >= 300 AND l.type <= 449)
        THEN 'Personal Loans'
        WHEN (l.type >= 450 AND l.TYPE <= 465)
        THEN 'Credit Card Loans'
        WHEN ((l.type >= 500 AND l.TYPE <= 510)
            OR (l.type >= 700 AND l.type <= 710))
        THEN 'Lines of Credit'
    END AS [Loan Description]
    , CASE WHEN lt.userdate1 IS NOT NULL
        AND ((l.type >= 1 AND l.type <= 299)
        OR (l.type >= 300 AND l.type <= 449))
    AND (lt.CREATIONDATE >= @StartDate AND lt.CREATIONDATE <= @EndDate)
    AND lt.type = 54
    AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    and lt.CREATIONDATE = (SELECT MAX(lt.creationdate)
        FROM dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
        WHERE lt.PARENTACCOUNT = l.PARENTACCOUNT
            AND lt.type = 54)
    THEN lt.PARENTACCOUNT
    END AS [Debt Protection]
from dbo.LOAN l
inner join arcu.ARCUUserCategory UCat
    ON UCat.UserNumber = l.USERCHAR2
JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
    ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
where l.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND (l.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND l.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
    AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND UCat.UserName IN (@UserName)
) q
GROUP BY q.[User ID]
    , q.LoanBalance
    , q.Loans
    , q.[Loan Description]
    , q.[User Name]
    , q.[Loan ID]
ORDER BY q.[User ID], q.[User Name], q.[Loan Description]
```

Is there another way for me to get the most recent lt.creationdate inside the case statement?

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: What is the version of the query that gives you the correct data?

Comment: The code that is already there gives me the correct data, it just takes 2 minutes to execute.

Comment: Oh, I see, I read right past the "in the where clause" bit, a mistakenly thought the original did not have that subquery to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using that correlated subquery, I'd suggest trying a JOIN to a similar non-correlated subquery.

```
...
JOIN (SELECT lt.PARENTACCOUNT, MAX(lt.creationdate) AS lastCDate
      FROM dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
      WHERE lt.type = 54
      GROUP BY lt.PARENTACCOUNT
) AS ltlastdates ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = ltlastdates.PARENTACCOUNT
...
```

You should then be able to use `ltlastdates.lastCDate` in the `CASE`.

Also, if there is not already one, an composite index on `LOANTRACKING(PARENTACCOUNT, type, creationdate)` would probably help quite a bit.